# How to remove title on Prompt Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

How to remove prompt title "localhost says " using jquery

Comment: You can't, it's set by the browser.

Comment: you need to use your own popup's

Comment: you can't change it. only thing you can do is ; use a library instead. http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/prompt/

Comment: You can't manipulate that. use jquery HTML model pop-up instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this can work. Also refer [same hear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023072/jquery-ui-dialog-how-to-initialize-without-a-title-bar).

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
```

Comment: read the question carefully.  Its about prompt not jquery ui dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Only you can use your own module windows.
Or libraries:

https://alertifyjs.org

http://bootboxjs.com/

http://t4t5.github.io/

Example from last link:

```
swal({


title: "An input!",
  text: "Write something interesting:",
  type: "input",
  showCancelButton: true,
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  animation: "slide-from-top",
  inputPlaceholder: "Write something"
},
function(inputValue){
  if (inputValue === false) return false;

  if (inputValue === "") {
    swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");
    return false
  }

  swal("Nice!", "You wrote: " + inputValue, "success");
});
```

You can find a lot of good libraries in google.